# Can we store huge array of objects into Redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I have an array of objects similar to this

```
MyArray({obj1:"obj1value",obj2:"obj2value",obj3:"obj3value"})
```

The length of above is 500 000. Can I push it into Redis? I tried Hmset but unable to get proper solution.

In order to store above array into MySql, performance is pretty much expensive. As I need to iterate every time for insert. Hence I thought to Go with Redis. I am using Node and Redis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis hash instead of redis list to store our data.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.hmset('myObject',
    {'obj1': 'objValue1',
     'obj2': 'objValue2',
     'obj3': 'objValue3'
});
```

Here, myObject is the name of your hash holding key-value pair inside it.
Result:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall myObject
1) "obj1"
2) "objValue1"
3) "obj2"
4) "objValue2"
5) "obj3"
6) "objValue3"
```

Comment: what if one of these objects is list ?      Eg : MyArray({obj1:"obj1value",obj2:["obj2valueA","obj2valueB","obj2valueC","obj2valueD"],obj3:"obj3value"}) @ankitsahay

Comment: Do you mean you have list of objects? Because what you have is not a list, its a dictionary/JSON.